# My launcher got deleted. I can't turn debugging on neither can I turn on the bluetooth. What to do?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, usb-debugging, launcher, lenovo

I am using Lenovo A7000. I was facing some problems related to the touch in my phone, so I did a factory reset without backing up the data. But because of this my only launcher also got deleted. I cant access the notification bar as nothing is happening if I pull it down. I can't even turn the USB debugging on. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Can you access the notification bar from the lockscreen?

Comment: No I can't else I would have turned the bluetooth on and would have recieved the .apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your device has been factory reset, you should go through the set up steps which will prompt you to sign in with your Google account.

Once you are successfully signed in, you will be able to install a launcher from the Google Play Store from your PC, and this will prompt the application to be installed on your device.

If the launcher doesn't get installed for whatever reason, you should be able to access the notification bar now, and get into `Settings` from there (rather than using a launcher) which should allow you to enable ADB or bluetooth and you can push the apk from there.

Answer (score 1):

Hope your device is connected to your google account. if so you can install you can install third-party launcher from play store from any system you have access to. just login on web using same google account and it will display your device when you try to install an app from play store. you may additionally like to install something like quick setting.

Comment: I did a factory reset so all the linked accounts got deleted.

Comment: Have you completed the setup steps after the factory reset? This should allow you to sign in with your Google account, right?

Comment: I wasnt completing the whole sign in process. Worked.
Thanks @1990clb

Comment: No problem, I've posted as an answer for the next guy :)